# Modifying and printing ArrayList during iteration

Tags: java, collections

I am trying to modify and print modified list at the same time.
Following is sample code:

```
public class Test {

    static List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>()
    {{
        add(1);
        add(2);
        add(3);
        add(4);
        add(5);
    }};
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        performTask();
    }

    private static void performTask()
    {
        int j = 0;
        ListIterator<Integer> iter = l.listIterator();
        while(iter.hasNext())
        {
            if(j == 3)
            {
                iter.add(6);
            }
            System.out.println(l.get(j));
            iter.next();
            ++j;
        }
    }
}
```

I am expecting output as `1,2,3,6,4,5` but the output is `1,2,3,6,4`. Also if I want to get output as `1,2,3,4,5,6` how the code should be modified?

Comment: Hmm..would downvoters care to explain what is wrong with question?

Comment: I was not a downvoter, your question seems fine to me, including both what you tried and what you were expecting.

Comment: Not your down-voter (yet), but have you run this with a debugger, and if so, what did you find out? Your code is not behaving as you expected that it should, and in this situation use of a debugger is very often the best way to get a solution.

Comment: I debugged it, the element is added to the list but I am not able to print it in same loop

Comment: I'm surprised this doesn't throw `ConcurrentModificationException` to be honest.

Comment: Found this in the documentation for `Collection`: *"Although they technically aren't collections, instances of Iterator and ListIterator can also allow modifications to be written through to the backing collection, and in some cases, modifications to the backing collection will be visible to the Iterator during iteration."* So **in some cases** the modifications to the backing collection are visible, but it's not guaranteed.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would actually forgo the `Iterator` in this case.
Instead try code like this:

```
List<Integer> list = ...;
for (int index = 0; index < list.size(); index++) {
    final Integer val = list.get(index);
    // did you want to add something once you reach an index
    // or was it once you find a particular value?  
    if (index == 3) {
        // to insert after the current index
        list.add(index + 1, 6);
        // to insert at the end of the list
        // list.add(6);
    }
    System.out.println(val);
}
```

Since the for loop is comparing `i` against `size()` each iteration, and `size()` is updated when an element is added to the list, this properly prints the new things that are added to the list (as long as they are added after the current index).

Comment: I think this is pretty a pretty good answer.  Looking at the documentation, the behavior of `ListIterator` appears to be left undefined in the OP's use case, so could change at any time depending on the implementation.  Best to use something with defined semantics if the OP needs to do this.  Or maybe the OP should implement their own Iterator.

Comment: Yes I should not have used iterator

Comment: @Asha this answer is undoubtedly good, but it doesn't explain why your code doesn't meet your expectations. If you want, I can add my point clarifying it.

Comment: This code doesn't look right to me. It is picking the items from l (l.get(index)) where as adding the item in list (a different variable list.add(index + 1, 6);). Also list is initialized to list = new ArrayList<>(); and hence empty, so how come for loop is even supposed to run?

Comment: @xtratic: I've taken your code and just corrected it functionally to make the program correct so it can produce correct output. Hope I haven't offended you in any kind :)

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi Yea sorry, I'd changed `l` to `list` but forgot to change it in one place, also I don't know or care where OP gets their list from, I just declared the list so that we know about it here.

Comment: @Andrew Tobilko it would be helpfull

Answer (score 1):

xtratic's answer's theme is brilliant (thumbs up bro) in terms of demonstrating what needs to be done for meeting OP's requirements but the code doesn't do it's job well so posting this code which is what OP wanted,

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(1);
list.add(2);
list.add(3);
list.add(4);
list.add(5);
for (int index = 0; index < list.size(); index++) {
    final Integer val = list.get(index);
    if (index == 3) { // index doesn't have to be compared with 3 and instead it can be compared with 0, 1 or 2 or 4
        list.add(5, 6); // we need to hardcodingly add 6 at 5th index in list else it will get added after 4 and will not be in sequence
    }
    System.out.println(val);
}
```

This outputs following sequence,

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Inside for loop, if we do this,

```
list.add(index+1, 6);
```

Then it produces wrong sequence as 6 is added at 4th index.

```
1
2
3
4
6
5
```